# Blank out all select list text within option tags

Tags: jquery, html-select, selectlist

Using this select list as an example:

```
<select name="my-list" id="my-list">
    <option value="Name 1">Simon</option>
    <option value="Name 2">Frank</option>
    <option value="Name 3">Bob</option>
    <option value="Name 4">Alex</option>
</select>
```

Using jQuery, I need to blank out all available option text displayed (Simon, Frank, Bob and Alex), i.e. I am after the following instead:

```
<select name="my-list" id="my-list">
    <option value="Name 1"></option>
    <option value="Name 2"></option>
    <option value="Name 3"></option>
    <option value="Name 4"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/t3kre/)</kbd>

```
$('#my-list option').text('');
```

---

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

`$('#my-list option')` -->refers to `option` inside element with id `my-list`

`$('#my-list option').text('');` set text to `''`

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be, But keep in mind that `.empty()` will also remove the `html nodes` inside the target element. I am suggesting this because you wanted to clear the contents inside the `option` tag.

```
$('#my-list option').empty();
```

Please read this : http://api.jquery.com/empty/

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t3kre/1/)